# Seal on Yixing Teapot (Characters identified: 吳紅芳制)

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal, transcription

I found this little teapot at a thrift store today, and am intrigued by the characters on the bottom.

[image]
[image]

Comment: note the top corner of the text is worn away, which is why it appears slightly different from the text in 宋靖宇's answer (◐‿◑)

Answer (score 1):

制 means made

吴 is a well-known family name in China,so it's obviously 吴红芳 is a name for a person

The mean of this seal is (made by 吴红芳)

Many handicraftsman like leave their name with a seal